# MySQL access denied problem - random, sudden password changes?

Tags: mysql, linux

It looks as if my MySQL password is randomly changing after some time. I lose access - i can't log in with the password. I have to set it up again for it to work, and after about one hour do it again.
I'm using it for a Spigot (Minecraft) authorization plugin which I have also on my proxy server (BungeeCord). I'm using Almalinux VPS.
The plugin needs connection with the database for it to work, and if it doesn't connect, I can't start the server.
So, generally, here's how it works: I've set up the password. In the config.yml file of the plugin, I've set up the correct credentials. I start the server, the plugin works fine... until it randomly see on the console an access  denied error, and then i can't join back the game server ('the database operation couldn't be completed'). I can't log in with the password to the mysql shell either, it says the same "Access denied for root@localhost. Using password: YES'. i have to type 'sudo mysql secure_installation' and then set up the password again, then restart the (game) servers and it works.. and then repeat the process. Plugin logs:

```
11/22/2023 04:53:43]: [nLogin] [ERROR] Failed to build the account using "WHERE `last_name` = ? AND `bedrock_id` IS NULL LIMIT 3" with values "[Kiler_630]"
java.sql.SQLException: [Database] Could not get a pooled connection.
    at com.nickuc.login.Î˝Î¶Î ÎŁÎ¶Ď€Ď‡Î¸Î±Î”Î´Î¸Ď†.d(:38)
    at com.nickuc.login.Î”Î¦ÎľÎ©ÎŁÎ±ÎłÎ»Î¸ÎµÎ“Î˛Ď‡.a(:205)
    at com.nickuc.login.Ď‡ÎąÎ´Î”ÎŁÎąÎ©Î·Î“.a(:151)
    at com.nickuc.login.Î¶ĎÎ›Ď‡Ď‡ÎĽÎ©ÎąĎÎşÎłÎżĎ€Î´Ď.a(:73)
    at com.nickuc.login.Î¸Î“Î¶ÎşÎ ĎÎ·ÎŁĎ‡Î©Î“ĎÎ¶Î“Î˛.a(:147)
    at com.nickuc.login.ĎÎąĎ…Î¦ĎÎ˛Î›Î¸Ď‰Î»Ď„.a(:43)
    at com.nickuc.login.ĎÎąĎ…Î¦ĎÎ˛Î›Î¸Ď‰Î»Ď„.a(:138)
    at com.nickuc.login.ĎĎ„ÎşÎşÎ¶ÎłÎşĎ„Î Î´Ď‚Ď‡Ď€Ď‡.b(:216)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at net.md_5.bungee.event.EventHandlerMethod.invoke(EventHandlerMethod.java:19)
    at net.md_5.bungee.event.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:49)
    at net.md_5.bungee.api.plugin.PluginManager.callEvent(PluginManager.java:413)
    at net.md_5.bungee.connection.InitialHandler.handle(InitialHandler.java:457)
    at net.md_5.bungee.protocol.packet.LoginRequest.handle(LoginRequest.java:66)
    at net.md_5.bungee.netty.HandlerBoss.channelRead(HandlerBoss.java:114)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:346)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:318)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: nlogin-hikaricp - Connection is not available, request timed out after 5000ms.
    at com.nickuc.login.lib.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createTimeoutException(HikariPool.java:696)
    at com.nickuc.login.lib.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:197)
    at com.nickuc.login.lib.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:162)
    at com.nickuc.login.lib.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:100)
    at com.nickuc.login.Î˝Î¶Î ÎŁÎ¶Ď€Ď‡Î¸Î±Î”Î´Î¸Ď†.d(:36)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at com.nickuc.login.lib.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
    at com.nickuc.login.lib.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.nickuc.login.lib.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:828)
    at com.nickuc.login.lib.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:448)
    at com.nickuc.login.lib.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:241)
    at com.nickuc.login.lib.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198)
    at com.nickuc.login.lib.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)
    at com.nickuc.login.lib.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364)
    at com.nickuc.login.lib.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206)
    at com.nickuc.login.lib.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476)
    at com.nickuc.login.lib.hikari.pool.HikariPool.access$100(HikariPool.java:71)
    at com.nickuc.login.lib.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:726)
    at com.nickuc.login.lib.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:712)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    ... 1 more
```